# Windows bat file to rename file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like a Windows batch file which would rename all files found in subdirectories.

An example of the original file name is `Clarity.Always.2015.this.WEB.P10.pdf`.

I would like the result to:

1. Replace all dots, except the file/extension dot, with spaces.
2. Remove all characters AFTER the first 4 numerical digits (year).
3. Enclose the year within parentheses.

So, I would like the resulting file name to be `Clarity Always (2015).pdf`.

I have tried to modify several examples I've seen here, to no avail, including variations of:

```bash
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=." %%F in ('dir /b "*.*"') do ren "%%F.%%G" "file %%F name.%%G"
for /f "delims=*" %a in ('dir File*_EN.txt /b /s') do ren "%a" File*_ENU.pdf
```

Comment: Showing what you have tried and what they did or did not achieve is something you should include in your question.

Comment: Is the year always surrounded by `.` ? As ever, an example of your failed code and some examples of the filenames involved clarify the matter. Especially mention any filenames that contain characters that have a special meaning to `cmd` like `!)(&` or space

Comment: My advice is don't use parentheses, `()`, in filenames, use brackets, `[]`, instead.

Comment: The year is not always after the third dot.  I'm willing to use brackets[ ] instead if that helps.  Other examples of file names The.most.you.get.1999.fgfd.fdgdf.pdf

Comment: when.2009.df.dfg.dg.wer.pdf

Comment: Yes, the year is always surrounded by .

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN (
 'dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "fullfilename=%%e"
 SET "filename=%%~ne"
 SET "fileext=%%~xe"
 CALL :findnewname
)

GOTO :EOF

:findnewname
FOR /L %%y IN (1980,1,2025) DO (
 IF "%filename%" neq "!filename:.%%y.=!" SET "newname=!filename:.%%y.=.:%%y:!"&FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=:" %%b IN ("!newname:.= !") DO ECHO REN "%fullfilename%" "%%b(%%c)%fileext%"

)

GOTO :EOF
```

Save the filename and extension in user-variables.

Test whether the string `.year.` appears in the name. If it does, replace `.year.` with `.:year:` (colons can't appear in a filename), then tokenise the resultant string, taking the opportunity to substitute spaces for the `.`s, pick up the pieces and glue them back together for the rename (which is disarmed by just being `echo`ed)

[revised to scan subdirectories]

Comment: Works GREAT, the only problem I'm having is it's not looking in and acting upon sub-directories of the sourcedir

Comment: Added `fullfilename`, assign name part only to `filename` and change the `ren` to use `fullfilename`. Note that `ren` allows only the name+extension as the new name, no path.